# Looking for analytical solution for differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, change-of-variable

I am trying to solve the following differential equation (DE) analytically for two cases of $f(x)$:
\begin{equation} 
\hspace{-35pt} 
y''(x) 
+ \left( {E-{e^{-2f\left(x \right)}} 
- 2{e^{-f\left( x \right)}} 
- \delta 
\left( {{C_0} + {C_1}{e^{-f\left( x \right)}} 
+ {C_2}{e^{-2f\left(x \right)}}} \right)} \right) 
y(x) = 0
\tag{Eq. $1$}
\end{equation}

For the first case: $f(x)=x$. By making a change in variable from $x$ to $z$ by setting  $z=\exp[-x]$.  I transformed Eq. $1$ to the following form which I know how to solve analytically:
\begin{equation} 
y''(z) + \frac{1}{z}y'(z) 
+ \frac{{\left( { - A + B\,z - C\,{z^2}} \right)}}{{{z^2}}} 
y(z) = 0
\tag{Eq. $2$}
\end{equation}

However, for the second case: $f(x)=\sinh x$, I tried the same thing by setting $z=\exp[-\sinh x]$  hoping to get a form similar to Eq. $2$, but was unable to do so. Nevertheless, for the second case, I would still like to convert it to a form similar to Eq. $2$ so that I can obtain an analytical solution. So. is there a way of doing this by using another transformation for $z$, which I had missed?
Any input will be most appreciated.
Thanks.